# How to solve org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Tags: eclipse, excel, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to login facebook by using excel sheet .In this program the excelsheet  is imports the username and password but it will shows error while Login functionality calls and  it will shows  no such element error
**my excel sheet is**

[image]

```
    FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("E:\\workspace99\\SeleniumAutomations\\OR\\Login_or.xls");
          Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
          Sheet s=w.getSheet("login");
          driver.findElement(By.id(s.getCell(0,1).getContents())).sendKeys("rishy9999@gmail.com");
          driver.findElement(By.id(s.getCell(1,1).getContents())).sendKeys("chandu");
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          driver.findElement(By.id(s.getCell(2,1).getContents())).click();
          Thread.sleep(5000);
it throws:

    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
      (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.116)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232923,platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 61 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_01'
    Session ID: 8258b613a2b39bccb3f9fa30624d3acd
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir3768_17298}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=34.0.1847.116, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
        at iostream.Login2.f(Login2.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: 1. try printing the value of the cell you are reading
2. what do you see as a behavior? does the browser get launched and the fb page has loaded?

Comment: browser launched and facebook url opened and fill the username and password field then shows faliure message

Comment: What is the id being used to click on login button?  What is the value of s.getCell(2,1).getContents()

Answer (score 0):

Please check your facebook Language selected is 'English(US)' and also your browser default locale on which you are trying to run is on en_US. I have seen the changes in "id" for different locale. For e.g., I have checked in browser locale with french and launched facebook. The id of the 'login' button is 'u_0_l'. For English(US) it is 'u_0_n'. I hope this might be one of the reason for that exception.

Comment: i was already tryed to login by takeing id as "u_0_l" but it was not working